# Парсинг JSON на node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Получаю get-запросом следующую строку:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Основная"
    }
]
```

Помогите пропарсить в массив. Пробую так:

```
var answer; // тот самый ответ сервера
result = JSON.parse(answer);
```

Синтаксис валится на второй строке с ошибкой:

```
undefined:1
[
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
   at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Полный листинг кода:

```
var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    path: '/xxx',
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'xxx'
    }
}

http.request(options, (response) => {
    var answer = '';
    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        answer += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', () => {
        console.log(typeof answer);
        answer = JSON.parse(answer);
        console.log(answer);
}).end()
```

Вот логи консоли:

```
string
[
    {
        "name": "Основная"
    }
]
```

дальше описание ошибки:

```
undefined:1
[
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.res.on (D:\Work\Dev\node.js\svoboda\requestHandlers.js:25:27)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Судя по ошибке и по примеру "строки"  - скорее  всего Вам приходит не строка, а уже распарсенный массив

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko и как Вы это поняли?

Comment: @Дмытрык нет, именно строка

Comment: что показывает `console.log(typeof answer)` ? Запустите непосредственно перед парсингом

Comment: @Дмытрык string

Comment: А так, что у вас в переменной `undefined`, который вы пытаетесь распарсить. Попробуйте выполнить `JSON.parse(undefined)`, получите такую же ошибку.

Comment: Приведите полный код запроса, полный код как вы парсите и получаете ответ.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko отредактировал пост

Comment: 1) Насколько помню, то `request` в коллбэке принимает 3 параметра, а первый из них - `error`. 2) Попробобывал бы сделать запрос на другой адрес; 3) `answer` просто бы объявил, ничего не присваивая

Comment: @Дмытрык, 1) http.request(options[, callback]) - это с документации ноды. 2) с этого адреса я получаю данные, о чем свидетельствует и отладка и логи в консоли

Comment: Мы Вашку отладку и логи в консоли не видим. А видим мы то, что `answer` является строкой уже при объявлении.

Comment: @Дмытрык отредактировал пост

Comment: Судя по логами, у вас все нормально парсится. Т.е. показывается string и JSON. Ошибка скорее всего происходит позже, когда снова начинает работать событие `data`. Поставьте `console.log(answer)` в событии `data`. Такое ощущение, что после `end` опять происходит `data`, потом `end` и вот здесь уже ошибка.

Comment: Разобрался. В строке answer за счет форматирования были \r \t \n и прочие, почистил их перед парсингом и все отработало.